# How can I run archetypes.querywidget test suite locally?

Tags: testing, plone

I need to make a fix at archetypes.querywidget and it's buildout is not creating the bin/test script.

Should I use buildout.coredev? do I need to change it's checkouts to run the tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Please use buildout.coredev for all core packages. See our docs for more details:

https://buildoutcoredev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html

Short version:

```
git clone -b 4.3 https://github.com/plone/buildout.coredev.git
cd buildout.coredev
python bootstrap.py
bin/buildout
bin/test -s archetypes.querywidget
```

If you want a specific version, you can either amend sources.cfg (make sure you don't commit), or just go to the directory and checkout a specific version manually.